# How can I install the Xlib.h header under Fedora ?

Tags: c++, x11

Recently I have tried to make a window under Fedora using c++ and X11.
I compiled the code and got a Error Message saying "fatal error: X11/Xlib.h: No such File or Directory".

I have looked throught some forums but I didnt find a good answer.
I have already installed X11 but it still doesnt work.

Comment: You headers you need will be in something like `libx11-devel`.

Comment: Oh... Thank you i think I solved the question with this